# DRRacket Not Responding on Windows 7 (SP1)

Tags: racket

My installation of DRRacket (6.0.1) is freezing on Windows 7 Enterprise (SP1) when it starts up.
I've tried installing DRRacket (6.1.1) but I get the same result.
The results are the same regardless of whether I install the 32-bit or 64-bit versions.
Can sameone help me figure out what the problem is? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating your Windows 7?

Comment: Did DrRacket 6.0.1 work previously?

Comment: @benrudgers no, this is the first time I'm installing DRRacket.

Comment: @DavidMerinos No, I haven't. I'm in a virtual environment running Windows 7 Enterprise so i can't update.

Comment: Hmmm, try installing CCleaner to uninstall and clean registry files then try re installing.

Comment: Can you normally install third party applications in the virtual environment?

Comment: @benrudgers Yes, I can. In this case, the problem was caused by an empty entry in my PATH variable. Removing the entry fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My PATH environment variable had the following empty entry:   "";
After removing it, DRRacket was able to startup.